# Regex for deleting dash and things after it

Tags: regex

My data for example is:

```
xyz-2-3 456-2 1-2-4 1
```

I want to get the answer `xyz`

I use `-*$` But nothing happens and the cursor only appear in the beginning and end of each line. what's wrong?

Comment: If you're trying to `deleting all dashes and things between them` you should end up with `xyz4 1` and not `xyz`. Please clarify your question so that it actually makes sense.

Comment: Specifying the language would be great. Also include some codes that you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-.*-
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/21

Comment: Thanks, It works. I use `-.*-*$` modified from your code to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-.*` to get all characters after `-`. then you can replace them

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  -.*?(-|[0-9]|.)$
```

And Replace by empty string.